# What needs to be taken care of after changing the UUID of the EFI system partition?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uuid

I need to change the UUID of my EFI partition (background: see below).

After changing the UUID -- what do I need to take care of (in order not to mess up the system)?

---

Background: After installing an additional hard drive I ("mistakenly") cloned the efi boot partition of my old drive (now sdb) to the new one (now sda).
I went on and installed Ubuntu and Windows on sda (and left old Ubuntu and old Windows in sdb).
Grub did find all 4 OSs but fails to boot the old Windows on sdb -- instead it boots the "new" windows. (Booting the "old" Win directly from the "BIOS" (UEFI) works). I am assuming this is due to the identical UUIDs of the two efi partitions that hold the respective Windows Boot Loaders.

The grub entry ("What I see when I press 'e' in the grub list") for the new windows would run the following (replaced my UUID with 1111-1111):

```
setparams ‘Windows Boot Manager (on dev/sda1)’

  insmod part_gtp
  insmod fat
  set root='hd0,gpt1'
  if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ] ; then
    seach --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1 1111-1111
  else
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1111-1111
  fi
  chainloader /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

the grub entry for the old windows is this

```
setparams ‘Windows Boot Manager (on dev/sdb1)’

  insmod part_gtp
  insmod fat
  set root='hd1,gpt1'
  if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ] ; then
    seach --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt1 1111-1111
  else
    search --no-floppy -fs-uuid --set=root 1111-1111
  fi
  chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```